# weights in multiplication

Tags: calculus

I understand I have an equation of two fractions $0 < A, B < 1$.

$$R = \dfrac{A+B}2,$$ where $0 < R, A, B <1$. I understand how to bias towards A or B by inserting weights k1,k2 to the equation, like

$$R = \dfrac{k_1A + k_2B}2,$$ where $k_1+k_2=1$.

how do I bias towards a variable in a multiplication scenario, i.e., $R = AB$ ? I sense it should be something like $R = (A+k_1)(B+k_2)$ but I cannot find the boundary conditions and relationship for $k_1,k_2$. Would appreciate your help!

By the way my range for A, B is 1/7 -> 1, with a step of 1/7th.
So A*B should be 1/49 (or as close as possible)

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: Not too sure what you are asking. Do you have any context for this?

I guess you can try
$$R=A^{k_1}B^{k_2}$$
with $k_1+k_2=1$.

Comment: Hi, its 0< R, A, B <1 , so this solution cannot be applied. Would I be looking at something like R = A^{1-k1}B^{1-k2} ?

Comment: The weighted arithmetic mean is simply $R = k_1A + k_2B,$ without dividing by $2.$ The equation $R = \frac{A+B}2$ then is what you get when $k_1=k_2=\frac12.$

Answer (score 1):

Because you started your question by asking about a sum which is really an arithmetic mean, people who responded have tended to interpret your "multiplication" question as a question about the geometric mean,
because the geometric mean has the same relationship to multiplication that the arithmetic mean has to addition.

For a weighted geometric mean, you would choose $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that 
$k_1+k_2=1,$ $0 \leq k_1 \leq 1,$ and $0 \leq k_2 \leq 1,$ and then the weighted geometric mean is
$$ R=A^{k_1}B^{k_2}.$$
Note that I wrote more conditions on $k_1$ and $k_2$ than you really need; in effect, I wrote four inequalities (two for $k_1,$ two for $k_2$) where only two are actually needed. For example, $0 \leq k_1$ and $0 \leq k_2$ would have been enough.

Alternatively, with the same conditions on $k_1$ and $k_2$ you could write
$$ R=A^{1 - k_1}B^{1 - k_2},$$
and this also would give a weighted geometric mean of the same kind, because the conditions imply that
$(1-k_1)+(1-k_2)=1,$ $0 \leq (1-k_1) \leq 1,$ and $0 \leq (1-k_2) \leq 1.$

The fact that $0 < R, A, B \leq 1$ is not a problem. These formulas work for any positive numbers.

Also observe that when $k_1 = k_2 = \frac12,$ you get the ordinary geometric mean,
$$ R = A^{1/2}B^{1/2} = \sqrt{AB}.$$

If you actually want a weighted *product,* so that equal weighting would give you
$R = AB,$ then you can simply double the exponents in the geometric mean.
For example, you can set
$$ R=A^{2k_1}B^{2k_2},$$
which gives you $R = AB$ when $k_1 = k_2 = \frac12.$

If you would prefer not to write the $2$ in each exponent, you can change the conditions so that $k_1+k_2=2,$ $0 \leq k_1 \leq 2,$ and $0 \leq k_2 \leq 2,$
and write
$$ R=A^{k_1}B^{k_2},$$
which gives you $R = AB$ when $k_1 = k_2 = 1$ and otherwise gives you a product weighted toward whichever factor has the greater exponent.

Answer (score 0):

From your first example, it looks like you want a formula for $R = f(k,A,B)$ where $\lim_{k \to 1} R = A$, and $\lim_{k \to 0} R = B$. The following is one possibility: $R = A^k B^{1-k}$, but I am not sure if this will behave as you want for any $0<k<1$.

Since R is the mean of A,B in your first example, perhaps you are looking for a [weighted geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_geometric_mean)?

$R = e^{k \ln(A)+(1-k)\ln(B)}$

Comment: Hi, so you propose instead of using two weights just use one, and find the neutral solution (bias-wise) at k=0.5? So k=0.6 biases towards B and k=0.4 biases towards A?

Comment: Yup. Sticking with $k_2=1-k_1$ I just wrote $k$ and $1-k$ instead of $k_1$ and $k_2$, same thing.

Comment: Note for k=0.5, this doesn't give you back AB. So you'd have to do some tweaking.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! The weighted mean does not give me AB rather than the mean of the two values for k=0.5, right? What do you mean by tweaking? On the weighted geometric mean or for the R=A^k*B^k ? I would need an equation that is close to that product when k=0.5, but I am not sure of how to approach this.

Comment: By the way my range for A, B is 1/7 -> 1, with a step of 1/7th.
So A*B should be 1/49 (or as close as possible)

Comment: By "tweaking" I meant setting it so that $R=AB$ for $k=0.5$, which turns out to be multiplying the exponents by 2: $R=A^{2k}B^{2(1-k)}$, as in @David K 's answer